# Failed to stream video on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to play videos using video tag and embed tag but failed to play that on google chrome whereas it should have done.

Following is the code that I have used to play it on every browser:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true"/>
   <title>Live Video Streaming</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <video id="video1" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4">

   <object width="640" height="360" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
     <param name="SRC" value="videoplayback.mp4">
     <p>Please update your browser or install Flash</p>

    <!--<embed  src="videoplayback.mp4"  
    width="640" height="360" type='video/mp4' controls>
        </embed>-->
       </object>
     </video>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Please help me.....thanks!

Comment: Please add details about what *exactly* does not work -- i.e. a more detailed definition of *it fails*

Comment: Add a Fiddle along with it too,along with the errors that you came up.

Comment: i have provided the source for the video that is played on IE and FF but that video is not running on chrome and just blank object is seen

Comment: Am still confused... it worked on FF ,but not on Chrome? 
Usually its the other way around.. anyway try my answer..

Answer (score 0):

From what you said,it could be either the source problem or video type.
You would have to provide additional encoding for Chrome to work (like this example taken from MDN as well):

```
<video controls>  
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">  
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.  
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browseres -->  
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the video source file path correctly. Sometimes ppl use src="./videos-filename" or absolute path can be mentioned